# How to add cell border to SheetJS .xlsx generated file?

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

I have a [SheetJS](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx) .xlsx generated file, but I have not been able to put `border` to the `cells`.

I have this:

[image]

And I need this:

[image]

Is there a way to do it with `SheetJS`? It will be cool if there's a way to apply another cell styles, like background color.

**EDIT**:

I'm making the sheets with this function:

```
function makeSheet(wb, day){        //sheet for a specific day
    var ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById("table"+day));
    wb.SheetNames.push(day);
    wb.Sheets[day] = ws;
    //columns width working ok
    wb["Sheets"][day]["!cols"] = [{ wpx : 70 },{ wpx : 121 }];
    //wb["Sheets"][day]["A1"]["s"] = {"border":"1px"};  //I've tried this but doesn't work
  return wb;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I've created this example snippet, if you can put borders and/or another cell style here, that's going to be a victory:

```js
$(document).ready(myMain);
function myMain(){
  $(document).on("click","#btnexcel", function(){makeExcel()});
}
function s2ab(s) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  return buf;
}
function makeExcel(){
 var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById("myTable"),{sheet:"Sheet 1"}) //my html table

 var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx',  bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});
 saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), 'MyExcel.xlsx');
}
```

```html
<!-- JQuery  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script lang="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.12.13/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnexcel">Download excel</button>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <thead><tr><th>hello</th><th>dear community</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>I need borders</td><td>around here</td></tr>
    <tr><td>I'll be glad</td><td>if you help me</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post your code as snippet using codepen/jsfiddle/plunker etc? That would be easy to debug

Comment: @VicJordan I've added part of my code.

Comment: please make a code snippet. I can not execute and see the output.

Comment: I had problems importing the required libraries.

Comment: What problem you are having? Where are you trying to create snippet? Try to add `cdn` link of lib

Comment: @VicJordan I've added a snippet, see my second edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using community version of `SheetJS` library and with this version **can not** do styling. BUT in [Pro Version](http://sheetjs.com/pro) styling feature is available.

Checkout this official comment:

> This is the community version. We also offer a pro version with
>   performance enhancements, additional features like **styling**, and
>   dedicated support.

For more information about Pro Version visit their official site: http://sheetjs.com/pro

Comment: I've sent an email and will see how much it will cost.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo have you got the reply? how much is the pro version cost?

Answer (score 1):

```
var wscols = [{wpx: 100}];
ws['!cols'] = wscols ;
```

Comment: I've tried this and doesn't work, can you explain how to make this work?

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo hey, I know it's so late to ask this question, but.... you know.. Did you get it work?

Comment: @Chawchawchaw I didn't but should be possible with sheetjs pro version.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo Thanks for reply. :)